# jax-ws secure web service client works inside NB web project but fails in java application project

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, netbeans, glassfish

Can somebody explain to me why does this happen?

I have created a simple web service using jax-ws in Netbeans 8.1. There I use  `plain SSL for authentication and confidentiality protection`.

After that, I have created a simple client that will consume the web service.

Now, if I create a client as **java application project** in the netbeans and run it -  the following error occurs :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Invalid Security Header Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cuase of the failure.
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:193)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:126)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:177)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:256)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:151)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.receiveData(Unknown Source)
    at wstest1client.WSTest1Client.receive(WSTest1Client.java:44)
    at wstest1client.WSTest1Client.main
```

and in server log I find:

```
 WSITPVD0035: Error in Verifying Security in Inbound Message.
com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: Security Requirements not met - No Security header in message
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.createMessage(SecurityRecipient.java:943)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.validateMessage(SecurityRecipient.java:256)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.provider.wsit.WSITServerAuthContext.verifyInboundMessage(WSITServerAuthContext.java:594)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.provider.wsit.WSITServerAuthContext.validateRequest(WSITServerAuthContext.java:364)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.provider.wsit.WSITServerAuthContext.validateRequest(WSITServerAuthContext.java:267)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:419)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:868)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:169)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However, **the same client code**,  when I run it from the inside of a **web project** (glassfish 4.1) - ***runs fine***!!

Is it a matter of some libraries or certificates? What is happening here?

Below are the source codes:

*Web service:*

```
package server;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;

@WebService(serviceName = "NewWebService")
public class NewWebService {
   @Resource
    private WebServiceContext wsc;

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "receiveData")
    public ArrayList receiveData(@WebParam(name = "res_number") final int res_number) {
        ArrayList res = new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0;i<res_number;i++)
            res.add(i);
        return res;
    }
}
```

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Constraint1</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>NewWebService</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <description/>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

*and finally the client*

```
public class NewClass {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(receive(5));
    }
    private static java.util.List<java.lang.Object> receive(int resNumber) {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","E:\\mylocalhost.jks"); //path to jks
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","*****"); 
        client.NewWebService_Service service = new client.NewWebService_Service();
        client.NewWebService port = service.getNewWebServicePort();
        java.util.Map<String,Object> rmap = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
        java.util.Map<String,List<String>> header= new HashMap();
        header.put("Username", Collections.singletonList("1"));
        header.put("Password", Collections.singletonList("1"));
        rmap.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS , header);
        rmap.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,"https://localhost:8181/WSTest1/NewWebService");
        return port.receiveData(resNumber);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.